# Add code before/after H type floats only

Tags: floats, xpatch, vspace

I would like to patch my `[H]` floats with some vertical space as it appears inconsistent with `[h]` and other type floats. I am using `KOMAscript`

Is there a good way to put code before/after the environment, only if `[H]` arg is passed? I can achieve the affect by manually putting `\vspace{}`, but obviously I'd rather not every time.

I would also like to avoid creating a new environment; I feel that having the native float declarations will make my .tex files usable/transferrable with other formats.

Alternatively, if you know a good way to make the spacing consistent, that would help.

EDIT: Adding a MWE

```
\documentclass[parskip=full,captions=tableheading]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[tableposition=top,labelfont=bf,skip=0pt]{caption}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{0pt}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{0pt}

\setlength{\intextsep}{\baselineskip}


\newcommand{\blah}{Here are some random words. Blah, blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.}


\begin{document}

    \blah

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \noindent\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-b} 
        \caption{h type figure, see the space below}
    \end{figure}

    \blah

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \noindent\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-b} 
        \caption{H type figure, see the extra space below}
    \end{figure}

    \blah

\end{document}
```

Comment: `[H]` should be using `\intextsep` the same as `h` floats.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, there is definitely more space under the H. I posted a MWE.

Comment: Congratulations -- You've discovered yet another reason why the `[H]` location specifier should be avoided entirely. Seriously: don't use it; use `[ht!]` instead.

Comment: @Mico, sigh, as many of us TeX noobies lament, but I **have** to have that table here, right HERE!

Comment: @likethevegetable - The belief that `[H]` will give you something better than `[ht!]` is an illusion, a mirage. *If* there's enough space left on the page to place the float, then `[H]` and `[ht!]` produce the exact same outcome. And if there's not enough space left on the page to place the float, then `[H]` and `[ht!]` will both place the page at the top of the next page. (Where else should the float go?!) The difference is that `[H]` will create a huge, unsightly gap at the bottom of the page that precedes the float, whereas `[ht!]` will not.

Comment: In addition to what Mico says, the _only_ reason to use  figure environment is to specify it can float, if you want an image to be part of the main document flow just use `\includegraphics` directly. marking a float then adding additional markup to make it non float makes no sense. `[H]` was my idea, but I was younger then, and wrong.

Comment: @Mico @DavidCarlisle thank you for the logical explanations, folks. I think what people are trying to avoid is if the float goes on the next page, they don't want content leaking in from the next section. Of course, this defies the benefit of using TeX and floats period. So I will definitely use the `[ht!]` recommendation, and if I absolutely need a figure/tabler HERE, a `center` environment with `\captionof` will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to patch the end command to add a negative \parskip:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full,captions=tableheading]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\float@endH{\relax}{\vskip-\parskip\relax}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\usepackage[tableposition=top,labelfont=bf,skip=0pt]{caption}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{0pt}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{0pt}

\setlength{\intextsep}{\baselineskip}


\newcommand{\blah}{Here are some random words. Blah, blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.}


\begin{document}

    \blah

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \noindent\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-b}
        \caption{h type figure, see the space below}
    \end{figure}

    \blah

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \noindent\includegraphics[height=5cm]{example-image-b}
        \caption{H type figure, see the extra space below}
    \end{figure}

    \blah

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you; I believe this is exactly what I need. I tested it out and it seems to produce what I desire. If you don't mind, can you please explain the @endH ? And if you really don't mind, if you broke down that particular patch entirely and explained it, I think I would learn a lot from it. Thanks regardless.

Comment: And another thing; if I was using `floatrow`, how would I do this?

Comment: Isn't `noindent` (before `\includegraphics`) superfluous?

Comment: @Zarko probably... hah. I'm pretty sure. I just copied that because I needed a MWE image.